# Automatically add text to an article on MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have a local MediaWiki running and I am developing a new extension. There's a new feature I want to implement, but I need to be able to add text to an article automatically.

In more detail, everytime someone creates or edits an article I want to inject additional text at the bottom, for example, `[[Category:TBD]]`.

I found two Hooks that seem to be the ones that can do the job:

- PageSaveComplete
- MultiContentSave

I tried both, but none of them is working.

**MultiContentSave**

```
public static function onMultiContentSave( RenderedRevision $renderedRevision,
                                            UserIdentity $user,
                                            CommentStoreComment $summary,
                                            $flags) 
{
    // get page content
    $content = $renderedRevision->getRevision()->getSlot('main')->getContent();

                // update content
    $data = $content->getText();
    $data .= "[[Category:TBD]]";

    $content1 = new WikitextContent($data);

    return true;
```

**PageSaveComplete**

```
public static function onPageSaveComplete( WikiPage $wikiPage, UserIdentity $user ) {

    $content = $wikiPage->getContent();
    $data = $content->getText();
    $data .= "[[Category:TBD]]";
    $data = ContentHandler::makeContent($data, $wikiPage->getTitle());

    echo("Saving...");

    $summary = CommentStoreComment::newUnsavedComment( 'test' );

    $updater = $wikiPage->newPageUpdater($user);
    $updater->setContent(SlotRecord::MAIN, $content);

    $updater->saveRevision($summary, 0);

    return true;

}
```

With the first approach nothing happens and in the second approach it keeps echoing "Saving..." until it runs out of memory.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: PageSaveComplete : do you add the category in an infinite loop, If onPageSaveComplete if triggered by itself ?

Comment: @IRA1777 that was my conclusion as well, but i'm not sure how to stop the loop...

Comment: IMO, the principle of this extension is not safe. I'm not sure what you want to achieve, functionally, but either an external bot or a combination of extensions (SMW + Page forms) are much safer.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations? I just want to automate the following:
1. User creates/edits an article
2. Automatically add a new category to that article

Comment: Depends if you will need further functionalities and it also on the "discipline" that you can expect from your users. Extension "Page forms" is very potent, but may be an overkill here. It allows you to have a template-based wiki, which is very nice.

Comment: @IRA1777 i only need something very basic as this is, for now, a simple prototype. I checked SMW yesterday, but I wasn't able to find anything that allowed me to do this automation :/

Comment: Well SMW can do almost anything, this extension is a jewel, but the "entry ticket" is expensive. Did you try to simply remove the supposed loop by checking is the page content already contains the category ? I still consider that building an extension for this type of functionality is dangerous. Maintaining extensions has been tricky in the past, and for the sake of security, MW updates are mandatory.

Comment: @IRA1777 I will try to implement while checking for the category, thank you. Because of MW updates we decided to go with an extension and due to the deadline I have to find a quick solution - for the long term, I'll try to find something better!

Answer (score 0):

How to close the loop : before editing, check if your category is already added by crawling page's content.

Is it just to be sure one category at least is present ?
Why not just using the "*Uncategorised pages*" given by the mediawiki engine ?

Exemple via wikipedia (fr, but same available in any languages) : [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spécial:Pages_non_catégorisées](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A9cial:Pages_non_cat%C3%A9goris%C3%A9es)